# Django group by dates and SUM values

Tags: mysql, django

Is it possible to reproduce the following mysql query in Django without using select method ?

```
MariaDB [db1]> SELECT datetime, SUM(datas) FROM table AND datetime BETWEEN '2013-07-26 13:00:00' AND '2013-07-26 23:00:00' GROUP BY datetime;
```

To get this kind of result :

```
+---------------------+-----------+
| datetime            | SUM(data) |
+---------------------+-----------+
| 2013-07-26 13:00:00 |       489 |
| 2013-07-26 14:00:00 |      2923 |
| 2013-07-26 15:00:00 |       984 |
| 2013-07-26 16:00:00 |      2795 |
| 2013-07-26 17:00:00 |      1308 |
| 2013-07-26 18:00:00 |      1365 |
| 2013-07-26 19:00:00 |      1331 |
| 2013-07-26 20:00:00 |       914 |
| 2013-07-26 21:00:00 |       919 |
| 2013-07-26 22:00:00 |       722 |
| 2013-07-26 23:00:00 |       731 |
+---------------------+-----------+
11 rows in set (1.45 sec)
```

Edit: I got for now this kind of query :

```
>>> value = table.objects.filter(datetime__range=('2013-07-26 13:00:00', 
 '2013-07-26 23:00:00')).values('datetime', 'data').annotate(Sum('data'))

>>> print value.query
SELECT `table`.`datetime`, `table`.`data` SUM(`table`.`imps`) AS `data__sum`
 FROM `table`
WHERE `table`.`datetime` BETWEEN 2013-07-26 13:00:00
and 2013-07-26 23:00:00 GROUP BY `table`.`datetime`,
`table`.`data` ORDER BY NULL
```

Why sum operate on both datetime and data?

I tried to everywhere on django doc, here on stack but didn't find something coherent with my problem.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: What SQL does your queryset generate? You can use `print values.query`

Comment: Switch the order of `.annotate()` and `.values()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmm you are using `Count`, you should use `Sum`, and `values()` will determine what goes into `GROUP BY` so you should use `values('datetime')` only. Your queryset should be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

values = self.model.objects.filter(
    datetime__range=(self.dates[0], self.dates[1])
).values('datetime').annotate(data_sum=Sum('data'))
```

although I'm not so sure about the order of the `filter()`, so it could be this:

```
values = self.model.objects.values('datetime').annotate(data_sum=Sum('data')).filter(
    datetime__range=(self.dates[0], self.dates[1])
)
```

I guess you would wanna try both then. If you want to see the raw query of those queryset, use `Queryset.query`:

```
print self.model.objects.filter(
    datetime__range=(self.dates[0], self.dates[1])
).values('datetime').annotate(data_sum=Sum('data')).query.__str__()
```

So you can make sure you get the right query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thx, why filter after annotate?

Comment: It's just I'm not sure about the result query of them so it could be either, anyway use `query.__str__()` to check the query you need. Also check my answer carefully, you should use `values('datetime')` only

Comment: Can you edit the answer to indicate which answer was correct?

Comment: I also needed to add an empty `.order_by()` to make this query work for me.

Comment: this will return results that are not grouped by date, there will be duplicated dates in results with different sums

Answer (score 7):

`order_by()` will get you `GROUP BY`:

```
values = self.model.objects.filter(datetime__range=(
    self.dates[0], self.dates[1])) \
    .values('datetime') \
    .annotate(data_sum=Sum('datas') \
    .order_by())
```

Comment: Does not work, sorry: SELECT `table`.`datetime`, `table`.`data` FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`datetime` BETWEEN 2013-07-26 13:00:00 and 2013-07-26 23:00:00) ORDER BY `table`.`datetime` ASC

Comment: It's alright I use Hieu Nguyen method's and the problem came from the values('datetime', 'data')

Comment: The empty `.order_by()` was critical for me. If I didn't do this, it did not group correctly.

Comment: what if i need more fields in returned results?