# Aggregating data (days) in template

Tags: python, django

I want to aggregate amount of item for each day separately.

Model:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

Template:

```
   {% with var=bill.date|date:"Y-m-d" %}
      {{ var }}   #dict?
   {% endwith %}
```

I think, that add date to dictionary as a key, and count amount of item as a value is a good idea, so I write it:

```
Dict[var] += bill.amount
```

How can I use it in Django template?

Am I on the right way? Maybe other solution are better?

Comment: hey, I've seen your comment that you have deleted. I added examples just now. You could have found them by googling/searching on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [aggregation/annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) to get [sum of amount by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099697/django-group-by-dates-and-sum-values). In template just simply print its value as usually with querysets.

**1. If you have datetime with same values (hours, minutes and seconds), you should be able to use the following.**

```
bills = Bill.objects.values('date').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

In template just use

```
{% for bill in bills %}
    {{ bill.date }} - {{ bill.sum__amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

**2. If you have datetime with different hours and you want to group by date and print its sum:**

```
bills = Bill.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( date )'})\
                    .values('day').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

And then print it:

```
{% for bill in bills %}
    {{ bill.day }} - {{ bill.sum__amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

**3. If you want to do calculations in template, which I strongly do not recommend, have a look at [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)**